# Internet Explorer 11 doesn't enter fullscreen via Fullscreen API

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, fullscreen

I am trying to use fullscreen api. API works correctly all other browsers, but unfortunately ie11 doesn't response. I am using this code which has copied from here:

```
var element = $doc.documentElement;
var requestMethod = element.requestFullScreen || element.webkitRequestFullScreen || element.mozRequestFullScreen || element.msRequestFullscreen;

    if (requestMethod) 
    { // Native full screen.
        console.log(requestMethod);
        requestMethod.call(element);
    } 
    else if (requestMethod !== "undefined") 
    { // Older IE.
        console.log("window.ActiveXObject !== undefined");
        var wscript = new ActiveXObject("Wscript.shell");
        wscript.SendKeys("{F11}"); 
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: A typo? `msRequestFullscreen`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko  Can't see it.

Comment: Forget it. I wasn't aware that IE uses 'Fullscreen' instead of `FullScreen`

Comment: [The spec suggests "Fullscreen"](https://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/#api), so Microsoft appears to have it right here.

Answer (score 4):

Ensure you're not using the invalid `msRequestFullScreen`, you need to be using the case-correct version, `msRequestFullscreen`. This is Microsoft specific as I think all of the other vendors made the `s` for the word screen uppercase.

Comment: like ftw, `document.getElementById("myelem").msRequestFullscreen()` executes, returnes undefined, but does not go into fullscreen on IE11...